# Python : how can I know which one of my dependencies is attempting to install a specific package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a project with a requirements.txt file that is quite big ( 67 dependencies ). One of the dependencies is attempting to use the psycopg2 package installed and fails. I would prefer to install the psycopg2-binary package

How can I find witch one of the dependencies requires psycopg2 ?

I have attempted to use `pip list` and `pip show psycopg2` but this only works if you package was installed correctly which is not my case

I have also attempted to use the `pydeps` tool such as `pydeps requirements.txt` but this gives me an assertion error witch I have yet to figure out

How can I know in advance which package is requiring directly or indirectly ( it can be through a dependency of one of my dependencies ) the psycopg2 package ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the utility [pipdeptree](https://pypi.org/project/pipdeptree/). It shows a tree of the packages used in a pip installation with the dependencies between them.

> One of the dependencies is attempting to use

Note that possibly more than one package is attempting to use that other package.

Comment: thank you for this tool it looks quite useful but I cannot use it on non installed packages and since the installation fails I cannot verify witch package or packages are attempting to use psycopg2

Comment: This might do that for you https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep

Answer (score 0):

`pip` by itself doesn't have this feature. You will need to use another tool. One option as Joshua Fox says is `pipdeptree`. Another alternative is to use [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/) for dependency management instead of pip. Poetry will create a lock file that shows the dependencies of each package which you install.